# Numerical approximation of the $\ell_p$ surface area

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, numerical-integration

What numerical method can approximately compute the $(n-1)$-dimensional surface area of the $\ell_p$ ball $\{x\in\mathbb R^n: \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p=1\}$, for $p\in[1,\infty)$? Ideally the method should handle $n$ and $p$ both in the range of 5 to 10.

One approach begins with the definition 
of surface area as $$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \frac{\mu_n(B_p + \varepsilon B_2)-\mu_n(B_p)}{\varepsilon},
$$
where $B_p$ and $B_2$ are unit $\ell_p$ and $\ell_2$ balls, using Monte Carlo to estimate the volume of both bodies. This method fails numerically, because when $\varepsilon\to 0^+$ the two volumes are very close to each other.

Another approach uses *Cauchy's integration formula*, which states that
the volume of $\partial B_p$ is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{\mu_{n-1}(B_2)}\int_{S_2}\mu_{n-1}(B _p|u) du,
$$
where $\mu_{n-1}(B_p|u)$ is the volume of $B_p$ projecting onto the orthogonal complement of $u$. However, this projection seems difficult to numerically approximate.

What approaches would provide a better approximation?

Comment: Are you aware of the formula for the volume of a p-ball: https://ergodicity.net/2010/07/02/a-nice-formula-for-the-volume-of-an-l_p-ball/   Can this help?

Comment: Hello Beni! Thanks for your suggestions. Yes I'm aware of the volume formula for p-ball but unfortunately it provides little help into the volume of a p-surface. A more extensive discussion can be found in this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234314/surface-area-of-an-ell-p-unit-ball?rq=1

Comment: What error in the estimation would you find acceptable?

Comment: Even in the 2d case I don’t see an especially good way to approximate the arclength, although the problem may be clarified by writing it as $$\frac{4}{p} \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1}{u^{2-2/p}}+\frac{1}{(1-u)^{2-2/p}}}du.$$

Comment: Maybe this could be of help? https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02084